# move_uploaded_file: failed to open stream: permission denied

Tags: php, linux, apache2

Нужно загрузить картинку на сервер но при переносе выдает ошибку .

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(/opt/lampp/htdocs/mySite/View/img/Зняток екрану з 2017-05-19 14-15-45.png): failed to open stream: Відмовлено у доступі in /opt/lampp/htdocs/mySite/Model/NewsModel.php on line 49
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/opt/lampp/temp/phpJjkc0l' to '/opt/lampp/htdocs/mySite/View/img/Зняток екрану з 2017-05-19 14-15-45.png' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/mySite/Model/NewsModel.php on line 49

КОД модели

```
public function setNews()
    {
        $uploads_dir=SITE_ROOT.'/View/img/';
        $tmp_file = $_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"];
        $file_name =$_FILES['photo']['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, $uploads_dir.$file_name); 
        $result= $this->db->query("INSERT INTO $this->table SET 
                           `title`='{$this->title}',
                           `short_content`='{$this->short_content}',
                           `text`='{$this->text}',
                           `photo`='{$file_name }';
                           `category_id`='{$this->category_id}',
                           `tags_id`='{$this->tags_id}'
                        ");
        return $result;
}
```

Я думаю проблема с правами доступа в Linux.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В папке temp поменял владельца на себя командой:

> chown -R anton /opt/lampp/temp

но показывает тоже самое.

Comment: приложите к вопросу (нажав [edit]) вывод команды `$ namei -l /opt/lampp/htdocs/mySite/View/img/; pgrep 'nginx|apache|httpd' | xargs ps -o user,command -p`

Comment: так у вас на момент выполнения был запущен хоть один процесс apache? если исполняемый файл называется как-то по-особому, посмотрите самостоятельно, от имени какого пользователя выполняются эти процессы.

Comment: selinux, случайно, не включен в вашей системе?

Comment: Не включе сделал скриншоты

Comment: Так и решения нету. Помогите!

Comment: 1. тектстовую информацию лучше приводить в виде текста. 2. вы так и не ответили, от чьего имени выполняется процесс apache. 3. отвечать даже и не надо, просто сделайте этого пользователя владельцем каталога, куда процесс не может записать файл: `/opt/lampp/htdocs/mySite/View/img`. 4. какое же **ещё** «решение» вам нужно???

Comment: как узнать от чьего имени выполняется процесс apache?

Comment: я написал это в первом же комментарии: `$ pgrep 'nginx|apache|httpd' | xargs ps -o user,command -p`

Comment: пишет ошыбка
$  pgrep 'nginx|apache|httpd' | xargs ps -o user,command -p
помилка: після -p має бути вказано список ідентифікаторів процесів

Користування:
 ps [параметри]

 Додаткову довідкову інформацію можна отримати
  за допомогою таких команд:   ps --help <simple|list|output|threads|misc|all>
  ps --help <s|l|o|t|m|a>

Докладніший опис можна знайти у ps(1).

Comment: замечательно! теперь переходим ко второму моему комментарию: «так у вас на момент выполнения был запущен хоть один процесс apache?». я оптимист, и надеюсь, что на каком-нибудь из кругов повтора у вас наконец-то всё получится!

Comment: Что это значит:
apache запещен и сайт я запустил на локалке и phpmyadmin Это считается запущеным процесом?

Comment: ну, если процессы apache запущены, так **посмотрите** сами (с помощью программы `ps`), от имени какого пользователя они работают.